# Como obtener el id desde un controlador de codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estoy modificando mi controlador para  obtener el id y enviarlo a la vista que tiene el rol ,los roles los manejo directamente desde la tabla default_users

```html
public function sendNew($msg = null)
{
       /*funcion para extrar el usuario logeado */
    $resu = $this->session->userdata('group_id');
  if ($resu == '100') {
      $this->template
    ->build('send');
  } else {
      $this->template
    ->build('sendusers');
  }
}
```

en el controlador siempre entra al else , 
lo hice con una consulta a la bases de datos la cual es la siguiente

```html
mysql_connect("localhost","root","imagina7192");
    mysql_select_db("intranet_gana");
  $cons = "SELECT * FROM `default_users` WHERE `group_id` = 100";

    $resu=mysql_query($cons);

    $resu = $this->session->userdata('group_id');
  if ($resu == '100') {
      $this->template
    ->build('send');
  } else {
      $this->template
    ->build('sendusers');
  }
```

El grupo_id es donde se maneja el rol el cual 100 es admin y  1 es un usuario sin permisos para ver la vista

Gracia antemano

Comment: Hola, no entiendo por que haces la conexión a base de datos en la linea `mysql_connect("localhost","root","imagina7192");` cuando las versiones 2.X para arriba de Codeigniter tienen integrado el modulo de conexión a base datos. ¿No leíste alguna documentación sobre el fichero **config/database.php** ?

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo lo que tratas de hacer, las conexiones en `codeigniter` son muy distintas, tiene su propia manera de realizar las consultas si tanto rollo y de una manera mas simple y para eso existen los modelos. Codeigniter tiene su propio archivo `database` dentro de la carpeta de `config` en el cual ingresas los datos de tu conexión a la `base de datos`.

Controlador:

```
public function obtenerServicios()
{
    //En la variable data guardo lo que me regrese el modelo
    $data['datos'] = $this->Inicio_model->obtenerServicios();

    //Al cargar una vista paso la variable data para mostrar posteriormente en la vista
    $this->load->view('main',$data);
}
```

Modelo:

```
public function obtenerServicios()
{
    $this->db->select('s.*,u.nombre as usuario');
    $this->db->from('servicios s');
    $this->db->join('usuarios u', 's.id_user = u.id');

    //realizo la consulta
    $aResult = $this->db->get();
    if(!$aResult->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    //retorno el arreglo de datos que me regresa la consulta
    return $aResult->result_array();
}
```

Es una manera tan simple de realizar las consultas a la base de datos que tu te estas complicando todo el trabajo.