# consultas traer dados de controlador base de datos a mi vista

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, controller, subconsultas

[me guie con este](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/491342/select-que-llene-input?noredirect=1#comment873288_491342) buenos días comunidad espero me puedan ayudar tengo en mi base de datos con nombre, correo, password y nivel

no se como mostrar el nivel que tiene esa persona al iniciar seccion ya que solo me muestra el correo
controlador

```
     if ($this->form_validation->run())   
    {  
        
        $data = array(  
            'correo' => $this->input->post('correo'),  
            'Nivel' => $this->input->post('Nivel'),  
            );    

                $this->session->set_userdata($data);  
                
            redirect('principal');  
    }
```

en mi vista

```
<a href="myprofile" class="d-block">   <?= $this->session->userdata('correo') ?></a>
    <a href="myprofile" class="d-block">   <?= $this->session->userdata('Nivel') ?></a>
```

y en mi modelo
public function log_in_correctly() {

```
    $this->db->where('correo', $this->input->post('correo'));  
    $this->db->where('password', $this->input->post('password'));  
    

  
    $query = $this->db->get('usuarios');  

    if ($query->num_rows() ==1)  
    {  
        return true;  
    } else {  
        return false;  
    }  

}
```

el correo si me lo muestra pero el nivel no, no se como traer el dato de nivel a mi modelo espero me puedan ayudar

> [Cita en bloque](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/153081/como-obtener-el-id-desde-un-controlador-de-codeigniter?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

si puedes mostrar el correo , deberias poder mostrar de la misma forma el nivel , veo en tu codigo Nivel esta con mayuscula, quizas en tu tabla este como nivel y por ello no te lo muestra.

```
$this->session->userdata('nivel')
```

Comment: hola esta bien escrito con Nivel

Comment: podria ser que en vez de retornar un true y un false en if ($query->num_rows() ==1)   , retornes 
$row = $query->row_array();
        return $row;
Y con ello puedas ver que es lo que devuelve tu query